# Count-- incrementing wrong

Tags: user-interface, timer, increment, countdown

I have made a GUI program in Java that you can start and stop a timer after you have picked 10 seconds, 5mins, or 1min. The numbers will count down but they are incrementing in 2. So it will go  10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0

Everything else is working fine but i cant seem to figure out what is wrong with the counter. Here is my code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class countdownPanel extends JPanel
{

    private ImageIcon banner;
    private JComboBox selectCombo;
    private JButton stopButton, startButton;
    private JLabel picture, theCount;
    private Timer timer;

    public countdownPanel()
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBackground(Color.black);

        //Banner Image
        banner = new ImageIcon ("banner.jpg");
        picture = new JLabel(banner);

        //Count Down selecter
        JComboBox selectCombo = new JComboBox();
        selectCombo.addItem("10 Seconds");
        selectCombo.addItem("1 Minute");
        selectCombo.addItem("5 Minutes");

        //countdown components
        theCount = new JLabel("   0");
        theCount.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 200));

        timer = new Timer(1000, new TimerListener());

        //Stop Start Buttons
        startButton = new JButton("Start");
        stopButton = new JButton("Stop");

        ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
        startButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        stopButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        selectCombo.addActionListener(new ComboListener());
        timer.addActionListener(new TimerListener());

        //GUI set up
        add(picture, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(startButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(selectCombo, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(stopButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(theCount, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }

//combo box listener
private class ComboListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        JComboBox levelCombo = (JComboBox) event.getSource();
        Object selected = levelCombo.getSelectedItem();

        if(selected.toString().equals("10 Seconds"))
            theCount.setText("10");

        if(selected.toString().equals("1 Minute"))
            theCount.setText("60");

        if(selected.toString().equals("5 Minutes"))
            theCount.setText("300");
    }
}

//Start and stop button listeners
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        Object source = event.getSource();

        //starts timer
        if (event.getSource()== startButton)
            timer.start();

        //stops timer
        if (event.getSource()== stopButton)
            timer.stop();

    }
}

private class TimerListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        String A = theCount.getText();
        int count = Integer.parseInt(A);

        while(count < 0)
        {
            count--;
            theCount.setText(""+ count);
        }

        if(count == 0)
            theCount.setText(" GO!");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: change count<0 to count>0 and see

Comment: I tried but then it doesn't countdown at all, count < 0 works and counts down the right way its just counting down by 2s which is weird.

Comment: if count<0 and you do count-- then this should give you negative count

Comment: Yes I know that is what i was also wondering why it is countdoing down right  it starts at 10 then goes  8, 6, 4, 2, 0    then I have it where it stops at 0. its just not counting by ones